# How to authenticate Python and Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets

There is a lot of conflicting information out there regarding authenticating Python with Google Sheets API. Mostly because oauth2 has been deprecated and replaced with google.oauth2.

Does anyone of you have a sample Python code that would authenticate via service key and return a range of columns from a specific sheet?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After mixing and matching I've come to a solution that finally works. Below code return list of lists (all columns in a row).

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'C:/Users/service_key.json')

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='1RKNGg7soVGbc8NauJ0LSIY4oPYdTJqUFSXzbtFD7jbk',range="A:C").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
for value in values:
    print(value[0],value[1])
```